# How to use sl4a or python-android with kivy and build this for smartphone?

Tags: android, python

I have a Python script which works on my smartphone in Qpython3 enviroment.

I am addding this script GUI with kivy and buld this script into `apk` file:

1. `pip install python-android`
2. Edit buildozer.spec: `requirements = kivy, android`
3. `buildozer -v android debug deploy run`. App succesfull building and deploing, and running
4. Next, I am running `adb logcat` and press start button in app. App closing and in the console I am seeing the following: http://pastebin.com/vyc68930

or short:

```
I/python  (24458):  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Android'
```

If I install python-android for python 3.4.3 on PC and `import android` I see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/android/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from boot import BootImage
ImportError: No module named 'boot'
```

If i am `import android` in qpython3 console on the smartphone and type `dir(android)` i am see: ['Android', ....]

If i am install python-android in the virtual environ on python 2.7.10 on PC and `import android` it's import without error, but after `dir(android)` i am don't see ['Android' ...]. It's not exists.

How can I use sl4a or python-android module with my project if I want to build it into an APK file?